# Redirect multiple dynamic URL to single static URL

Tags: .htaccess

We have multiple old URLs such as:

```
blog/index.php?d=26&m=12&y=11   
blog/index.php?m=03&y=12&d=22&entry=entry120322-135153
blog/index.php?m=06&y=12&d=&entry=entry120602-191105    
blog/index.php?d=19&m=02&y=12
```

The logic is always ?d, ?m, or ?y after the index.php.

I need to redirect these all to:

```
www.domain.com/blog
```

I've tried several different methods from here, but seem to be getting the logic mixed.

## Addendum

Following the TerryE suggestion, when I type in the link

> `http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog/index.php?m=12&y=11&d=26&entry=entry111226-110412`

in my browser, it resolves to

> `http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog/?m=12&y=11&d=26&entry=entry111226-110412`

(the index.php is removed). However, it is not going to

> `http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog`

I am also putting it above the wordpress one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why not provide some of those examples? Also, *redirect* or *rewrite*?

Comment: Sorry animuson...not sure what you mean between redirect or rewrite.  Basically, all the old blog pages no longer exist, so I need all the old blog addresses to redirect to the main/new blog feed page.

Comment: A redirect actually causes the user to completely reload the page and change to the path specified, while a rewrite just rewrites the path to something else internally. They're similar words but mean completely different things.

Comment: In that case, I would think I need a "redirect"?  Again, the old pages no longer exist.  I need to redirect them from all of the old pages to the new blog page.  Is that correct?  Does that influence TerrE's code he provided?

Comment: Sorry...edited above to show what I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a **QUERY_STRING** condition to look at the parameters, for example:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase    /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(d|m|y)=\d
RewriteRule blog/index.php  http://www.domain.com/blog?  [R=302,L]
```

If you want to keep the parameters, then drop the ? in the redirect string.  However, *if* you do this and the target redirects to the same directory then you'll need extra conditions to prevent a direction loop.

Once you've got this working swap the 302 to 301.  For more on this see [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

## Addendum following bump request

If you have an `.htaccess` in `DOCROOT/blog` then you need to insert this below the RewriteBase and above the first WP cond/rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(d|m|y)=\d
RewriteRule index.php       http://www.domain.com/blog/?  [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Terry, thank you for the assisance, however, it does not seem to be working.  When I type in the link http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog/index.php?m=12&y=11&d=26&entry=entry111226-110412 in my browser, it resolves to http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog/?m=12&y=11&d=26&entry=entry111226-110412 (the index.php is removed).  However, it is not going to "http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog".  Any ideas?

Comment: I am also putting it above the wordpress one: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I've updated your Q.  Putting complex code in comments is not a good idea as the formatting is stripped out.  If you want to loose the query parameters, then you **must** keep the last `?`before the flags in the RewriteRule).

Comment: Thanks TerryE.  I added in the code you gave me, leaving in the ? in.  If I leave the L in, I get a 500 Server error.  If I take out the L, then it redirects me, but keeps the query parameters?

Comment: @user1533776, no it's fine to bump.  Just slipped through the net.  Sorry.  I'll take a look later today.  I am in the middle of something now. :-(

Comment: Thanks so much TerryE.  I really appreciate your help.  I have comments above and below.  Sorry I'm being dense.  From animuson's post, I may need redirects rather than rewrites?  Not sure.  Basically have a bunch of links to old posts etc that no longer exist, when user types them in, I need them sent to the new blog index page.  :)

Comment: Do you have a `DOCROOT/blog/.htaccess`?  I've looked at your site and I suspect that this is was is screwing things up.  Move the rule to this file as I suggest above.  This will stop the 500 loop.  PS.  I like your site.  My wife's been doing yoga for 40 years :) I am lapsed :(

Comment: Hey Terry...my wordpress install sits in the root directory...and because it's wordpress, there is no folder called "blog", as it's just a permalink for the blog page (www.coreyogaasia.com/blog).  And thanks for the comments on the site!  I'm lapsed as well.  LOL

Comment: The redirect that you are getting is consistent with leaving out the `?`.  That's why you need it. The issue is "what is causing the 500 redirect loop?" when you leave it in.  Are you using `http://www.coreyogaasia.com/blog/?` in you replacement string (note the `/`).

Comment: How about ticking my answer then? :-)

Comment: Sorry bud.  Don't use this site often.  Hope that was what needed to be done!  Cheers!